# Регулярное выражение для вопросительных предложений

Tags: регулярные-выражения

хочу написать выражение, которое бы выделяло все вопросительные предложения, в которых слово более 2 символов встречается 3 и больше раз. С выделением слова и вопросительным предложением я, вроде как, справился, но не пойму, как сделать так, чтобы он проверял наличие этого слова 4 раза в предложении, подскажите пожалуйста, вот, что есть:

```
(?=[^!.?]*((?<=[\s.!?]|^)\w{3,}(?=[\s?.!])))[^.?!]+\?
```

https://regex101.com/r/ec8FQj/1
В следующем примере хотелось бы, чтобы он выделил первое выражение, но не выделял второе:

```
How are you How How How? Ghbdtn?
```

Answer (score 1):

Извините за вопрос, получилось

```
(?=[^!.?]*((?<=[\s.!?]|^)\w{3,}(?=[\s?.!]))(?:.*\1){3,})[^.?!]+\?
```